# How to change selected value of React-Bootstrap-Typeahead from HOC

Tags: reactjs, typeahead, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have two Typeahead (react-bootstrap-typeahead) component and I want to reverse selected values when pressed a button. The data which stored in state changing correctly. But I can't set changed selections to a value of Typeahead.

Used `selected` prop to set selected object but got some errors:

`` Warning: [react-bootstrap-typeahead] `defaultInputValue` will be overridden by the value from `selected`. ``

`` Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `selected` supplied to `TypeaheadContainer(WrappedTypeahead)`. ``

My HOC

```
<TypeaheadComponent
    onSearch={value => getOriginPlaces(value, index)}
    data={route.originResults}
    onInputChange={value => originPlaceInputOnChange(value, index)}
    onSelect={item => originPlaceOnSelect(item, index)}
    selected={route.originPlace} // object
    inputValue={route.originPlaceInputValue} // string from  originPlaceInputOnChange()
/>
```

And AsyncTypeahead (react-bootstrap-typeahead)

```
<AsyncTypeahead
    promptText={<PromptText />}
    searchText={<Loading />}
    emptyLabel={<NotFound />}
    inputProps={{...}}
    options={props.data}
    maxResults={10}
    paginationText={...}
    labelKey="name"
    filterBy={[...]}
    onSearch={props.onSearch}
    minLength={2}
    selectHintOnEnter={true}
    onInputChange={props.onInputChange}
    onChange={selected => props.onSelect(selected[0])} // set first object of array
    defaultInputValue={props.inputValue || ''}
    selected={props.selected} // object
    renderMenu={...}
/>
```

How can I do this? Or where I am wrong

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that `selected` needs to be an array, not an object. Try passing an array containing the selection (eg: `[props.selected]`) to the AsyncTypeahead. That should work.

For the second warning, `defaultInputValue` will set the input value only when the typeahead initially mounts (not subsequent renders), and any input value derived from `selected` will take precedence.

Comment: Hi @ericgio, Actually what you are tryin to acheive in 'selected' prop?, Cause im kinda getting the inspiration from your 'React-Async-TypeAhead' thing to implement on my Own. in my case, i need to fire up some api if selection is changed and select value is set.Thanks!